# Lp functions regularity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Let $g(x,\theta) = \int_{-a}^0 f(x+t\theta)dt$. If $f$ is in $L^p$ then $g$ is in $L^p$.

Proof.

$|g(x,\theta)|^p = |\int_{-a}^0 f(x+t\theta)|^p \leq |a|^p\int_{-a}^0 |f(x+t\theta)|^pdt$ by Cauchy Schwartz.

Thus;
$||g(x,\theta)||_{L^p(\Omega \times S^1)}^p = \displaystyle\int_{\Omega \times S^1}|g(x,\theta)|^p dxd\theta \leq |a|^p \int_{\Omega \times S^1}\int_{-a}^0 |f(x+t\theta)|^p dt dxd\theta$

How can I continue from here? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are the hypothesis on $f$? I think your first inequality is wrong, at least the result won't follow from Cauchy-Schwarz, maybe you can get something similar with Jensen inequality?

Comment: I guess you need the Holder inequality: $$\left |\int\limits_{-a}^0f(x+t\theta)\,dt \right |\le a^{p/q}\int\limits_{-a}^0|f(x+t\theta)|^p\,dt $$ Still you should specify what $\Omega$ and $S^1$ are.

Comment: $\Omega$ is strongly convex subset of $R^2$ and $S^1$ the unit circle. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Then the function $f$ should be defined on the region $\Omega +[-a,0]S^1.$

Comment: Ok. Then how can I continue from here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is defined on $\Omega'=\Omega + [-a,0]\cdot S^1,$ where $+$ and $\cdot $ denote the complex sum and the complex product of sets. We may think actually that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by setting $f(x)=0$ for  $x\notin \Omega'.$
Fix $t\in [-a,0]$ and $\theta\in S^1.$ Then
$$\int\limits_\Omega |f(x+t\theta)|^p\,dx \le \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x+t\theta)|^p\,dx=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x)|^p\,dx=\|f\|_p^p$$
By the Hölder inequality we get
$$|g(x,\theta)|^p=\left |\int\limits_{-a}^0f(x+t\theta)\,dt\right |^p \le
a^{p/q}\int\limits_{-a}^0|f(x+t\theta)|^p\,dt ,
\quad q={p\over p-1}$$
Therefore
$$\iint\limits_{\Omega\times S^1} |g(x,\theta)|^p\,dx\,d\theta \le a^{p/q}\int\limits_{-a}^0 \int\limits_{S^1}\left [\int\limits_{\Omega}|f(x+t\theta)|^p\,dx\right ]\,d\theta \,dt\\
\le 2\pi a^{p/q}a\|f\|_p^p=2\pi a^p\|f\|_p^p$$